# Cannot verify password with password_verify

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, passwords

I'm trying to achieve a redirect to the home page of the user storing email in the session in Codeigniter. I have used `password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT))` to hash the passwords and it works fine, but when I try to `password_verify()` it, it fails.

Here is my Model

```
public function canLogin($email, $password) {
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query  =   $this->db->get($this->tableName);
    $row    =   $query->row();
    if ($row) {
        return password_verify($password, $row->password);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is my Controller

```
public function loginValidation() {
    // User Model Loaded in constructor
    if ($this->user->canLogin($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $session_data   =   array('email' => $_POST['email'] );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        redirect('profile/personal','Refresh');

    } else {
        echo 'fail';
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
        // redirect('login','Refresh');
    }
}
```

I don't know where the logic went wrong and it everytime redirects to the same login page, I am trying to authenticate it, store email in session and redirect it to `profile/personal` , Can anyone point where I missed the logic?

Comment: Are you sure this code is running? Like, maybe the login form action isn't set and it's submitting to itself instead of the `loginValidation` route. Just a thought.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix He didn't like your ternary operator. :)

Comment: @Dharman Right, I remember, but for the sake of question, I elaborated it to your version

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm positive the code is running as it is always echoing fail as XHR result

Comment: @YashKaranke what is the password column's length?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is 50 with datatype `varchar`

Comment: Ah, I was just thinking it might be that since you had the redirect to login commented out and were still ending up back at login. Apparently not, though

Comment: needs to be longer than 50. Check the password_hash manual.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sure will do

Comment: I have changed the title, as it was misleading. This should help others find it faster

Comment: @Dharman Sure, whatever helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @YashKaranke what is the password column's length? – Funk Forty Niner
>   @FunkFortyNiner It is 50 with datatype varchar – Yash Karanke

The password column's length is too short, it should be 60 or 255 as [the manual on PHP.net for `password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) suggests.

You now have to start over with new hashes.

The verification failed *silently*.

Comment: @YashKaranke Nothing to feel stupid about :) it happens.

Comment: @YashKaranke In general don't skimp on varchar max length.

Comment: annnnd the AJAX call isn't taking place now, I hate my life :)))) but thank you guys this helped a LOT

Answer (score 1):

If you're using:

```
password_hash($this->input->post('password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

Are you sure this is hashing correctly? Shouldn't it be:

```
password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: @YashKaranke "I made a typo..", question closed? or you made a typo pasting it in here?